# C# ProcessStartInfo: Second process receives no arguments

Tags: c#, .net, process

I'm trying to make a call from one process to start another, supplying starting arguments as separate parameters in a `ProcessStartInfo`. The starting call uses a URL registered in Windows to find the second program, entered into `FileName`. I then add a string containing 4 parameters to `Arguments`. As I have understood it, the spaces in the string indicate the separation of the arguments.

**Program 1**

```
//Create starting information
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo() {
    FileName = "urlHandle:",
    Arguments = "/argA valueA /argB valueB"
};

//Start second program
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
```

**Program 2**

```
//Print received arguments to a file
Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().ToList().ForEach(a => writer.WriteLine(a + ",\t"));
```

The second program starts as intended (meaning the URL is working), but the output is incomplete.

> [path to .exe of second program],
>
> urlHandle:,

It contains the path to the program, the string set as `FileName` , but everything put into `Arguments` is missing.

Does anybody have any ideas why the arguments disappear?

*Note 1:* If I would add the arguments into the `FileName`, I would receive them as one string. In order to trigger the behaviour I want in the second program, I must supply it with several parameters instead of one. I know this is possible from testing it manually from the terminal.

*Note 2:* I'm using .Net Framework, so trying `ArgumentList` from .Net Core is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more tests I have found the issue. The error does not lie in how I set up and use `ProcessStartInfo`, but rather in that I am using a custom URL protocol.

In the Windows registry one defines the number of parameters that can be sent via the URL call (`"C:\[path to my .exe]" "%1"`). The first argument is the `Filename`, and is as such the only thing sent via the protocol. In order to send more, one is required to add `"%2"`, `"%3"`, etc.

*Note:* The path itself becomes argument 0 in the receiving program, while the actual sent parameters start at argument 1 and beyond.